# Can 2d array be converted to usable list

Tags: linq, c#-3.0

I have a 2d array with values like this:

```
[0,1] = "A"
[0,2] = "A"
[0,3] = "A"
[0,4] = "A"
[0,5] = "A"
....
[1,0] = "1"
[1,1] = "2"
[1,2] = "3"
...
[2,0] = "N"
[2,1] = "N"
[2,2] = "N"
[2,3] = "N"
... So on.
```

Is there a way to convert this to 3 seperate lists like list1 will have all values of [0,1] [0,2]... so on. and List2 will have values of [1,0] [1,1]... so on. As i tried this:

```
List<string> cList = class.KVal.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

And this gives me a list but its not usable because i cant run operations on this as it has stored all values in one list.

I am trying following code:

```
 var theList = Enumerable.Range(0, table.KVal.GetLength(1) - 1)
                                         .Where(i=> table.KVal[0, i].Contains("A"))
                                         .ToList();
```

And than once i get all the A values i want that to be a basic index of getting values from next 2d array like above code gets value from 0 next when it comes to 1. I want it to get exactly the same values above code got.

So i am doing this:

```
var index = Enumerable.Range(0, table.KVal.GetLength(1) - 1)
                                         .Where(i=> table.KVal[0, i].Contains("A"))
                                         .ToArray();
```

I am not sure though how i can implement this array to get other values.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx):

```
var list1 = Enumerable
    .Range(1, table.KVal.GetLength(1) - 1) // if you want to start at [0, 1]
    .Select(i => table.KVal[0, i])
    .ToList();
var list2 = Enumerable
    .Range(0, table.KVal.GetLength(1))     // if you want to start at [1, 0]
    .Select(i => table.KVal[1, i])
    .ToList();
```

And so on.

Note that you can actually use this technique to traverse the array with *n* iterators:

```
var results = 
    from x in Enumerable.Range(0, table.KVal.GetLength(0))
    from y in Enumerable.Range(0, table.KVal.GetLength(1))
    select table.KVal[x, y];
```

This is a very simple example, but it illustrates how you can access a multidimensional array in a single Linq query.

Comment: above code is giving me list of bool why is that? Shouldnt it return list of strings?

Comment: @NoviceMe It should return an `IEnumerable<string>`. Can you show precisely how you're using it?

Comment: I am trying to add above list to variable l like this: l.AddRange(list); But it is giving me error saying list is bool.

Comment: @NoviceMe Sorry, but I'm going to have to see more code than that.

Comment: actually i modified the query thats why may be its changing it to bool. .Where(i => table.KVal[0, i].Contains("A"))

Comment: @NoviceMe If you just replaced `.Select(i => table.KVal[1, i])` with `.Where(i => table.KVal[0, i].Contains("A")` it will return an `IEnumerable<int>`. If you show your complete code, I can probably help you spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I updated what exactly i am trying to do above in the question.